# CollectionViewSource doesn't update the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, collectionviewsource, icollectionview

I am trying to implement a filtering and paging on a `ListView`. I managed to do the filtering but I observed that the UI doesn't get updated when I am adding/removing items from the collection.

Here is my setup:
XAML:

```
   <ListView
           ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

VM Side:

```
  private CollectionViewSource _usersCollection;
```

CTOR

```
  _usersCollection = new CollectionViewSource {Source = UsersCollection};
  _usersCollection.Filter += usersCollection_Filter;
```

Props:

```
  public ICollectionView SourceCollection => _usersCollection.View;
  public List<User> UsersCollection => LiteDbHelper.GetAllUsers();
```

Then when I am adding a new item I tried to `Refresh()` the collection (both `SourceCollection` and `_usersCollection`) with no luck, also tried to `RaisePropertyChanged` on `UsersCollection`, again with no luck. The UI stays the same as the first time created.

P.S. I am adding records to a file-DB (LiteDB) and then I need to retrieve them from the DB and update the UI. This worked till I started to use the `ICollectionView`.

Any hints?

Update: 
I managed to fix this issue with the following code:

Changed the property that was feeding the `CollectionViewSource`:

```
 private ObservableCollection<User> _usersCollectionDB = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    public ObservableCollection<User> UsersCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_usersCollectionDB.Count == 0)
            {
                var allUsers = LiteDbHelper.GetAllUsers();
                _usersCollectionDB.AddRange(allUsers);
                return _usersCollectionDB;
            }

            return _usersCollectionDB;

        }
        set => _usersCollectionDB = value;
    }
```

and on the add method I just used these lines and it worked:

```
        var allUsers = LiteDbHelper.GetAllUsers();
        _usersCollectionDB.Clear();
        _usersCollectionDB.AddRange(allUsers);

        _usersCollection.View.Refresh();
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the records and update the source collection?

Comment: With this: LiteDbHelper.GetAllUsers, and in the begining I only raised the property to get the new values, but now with the ICollectionView it doesn't work anymore

Comment: You need to reset the Source property. Please post your code.

Comment: I cleaned my vm in order to contain only the stuff for this issue: https://pastebin.com/vpi7VqVS  AddUserMethod - is called when I add a new user to database

Comment: You haven't posted any AddUserMethod. Please post the relevant parts of your code here instead of referring to some external link.

Comment: The relevant part from that method I posted it on the last code block on edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your source collection is a simple list:

```
List<User> UsersCollection => LiteDbHelper.GetAllUsers();
_usersCollection = new CollectionViewSource { Source = UsersCollection };
```

This is the reason you won't get any UI updates. The `UsersCollection` property will be queried by the `CollectionViewSource` one time, so the `CollectionViewSource`'s instance will work only with that single list of items that were retrieved on initialization.

If you check out [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource?view=netframework-4.7.2), you will see the following:

> If the source collection implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, the changes raised by the `CollectionChanged` event are propagated to the views.

The source collection needs to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. That's e.g. an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

So the solution is: instead of using dynamically created lists, you should use an `ObservableCollection<User>` as a source for the `CollectionViewSource`.

```
ObservableCollection<User> usersObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>();
_usersCollection = new CollectionViewSource { Source = usersObservableCollection };
```

Additionally, you will need to change your code so that this `usersObservableCollection` is populated by the items from your database.

Comment: I modified the Source to be a ObservableCollection and still is not working, I even forced a raise of the usersObservableCollection but the UI remains the same.